# Upsert a list with Simple.Data

Tags: c#, sql, simple.data

Trying to do a:

```
var list = new List<MyType>();
list.Add(new MyType() { PK1 = 1, PK2 = 2 });
list.Add(new MyType() { PK1 = 1, PK2 = 3 });
Database.Open().MySchema.MyTable.Upsert(list);
```

Nothing seems to happen, do i need to do a foreach or can i achieve this some how?

Comment: you aren't closing your brackets with your object initializer

Comment: That should work, see https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/blob/master/Simple.Data.SqlTest/UpsertTests.cs#L94 for example from test suite. Which back-end DB are you using?

Comment: Thanks, read @jakobras answer. Needed to do a .ToArray() to make it execute!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work, or any other enumeration of the result.

`Database.Open().MySchema.MyTable.Upsert(list).ToArray();`

Although it will not generate a batch SQL query, there will be a lot of queries to the database, at least for SQL Server.

Comment: One of the headline features for Simple.Data 2 is batch operations.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
Database.Open().MySchema.MyTable.Upsert( new MyType { PK1 = 1, PK2 = 2 } );
```

work?

ToArray() -

```
var list = new List<MyType>();
list.Add(new MyType() { PK1 = 1, PK2 = 2 });
list.Add(new MyType() { PK1 = 1, PK2 = 3 });
Database.Open().MySchema.MyTable.Upsert(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: Yes, that works but the point of the question is todo a batch. Not one at a time.

Comment: Look at the documentation. Can you Upsert a list?

Comment: Try ToArray() from a quick look at the documentation.

Comment: What documentation do you look at, in the documentation at simplefx only upsert only says forthcoming? Anyhow, does not seem to work.

Comment: Everything is on GitHub. https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data Look through the code.

Comment: Did that, and it seems like a simple array will not work. Its a cast to a dictionary.

Comment: The ToArray() needed to be outside the Upsert(x).ToArray(), thanks =)

Comment: Looking at the documentation and looking at the code are not the same thing. It is helpful if you make this distinction as it saves people looking in the wrong place like Lars and myself were. Still, grateful for the pointer.